# CLIMADA-Return Period outputs do not match impact exceedance curve

Tags: cdo-climate, microclimate

I'm calculating return period impacts for a single line of exposure in CLIMADA. I got the below output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwb7R.png)

For the same data set, I tried to output the Exceedanc frequency curve ,which should normaly match the return period data. But there is no match.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Xr8.png)

I tried to manipulate the return period inputs by changing the range. But nothing happened. I tried to go over codes used to output the return period showb below;

def local_exceedance_imp(self, return_periods=(25, 50, 100, 250)):
"""Compute exceedance impact map for given return periods.
Requires attribute imp_mat.

```
    Parameters
    ----------
    return_periods : Any, optional
        return periods to consider
        Dafault is (25, 50, 100, 250)

    Returns
    -------
    np.array
    """
    LOGGER.info('Computing exceedance impact map for return periods: %s',
                return_periods)
    if self.imp_mat.size == 0:
        raise ValueError('Attribute imp_mat is empty. Recalculate Impact'
                         'instance with parameter save_mat=True')
    num_cen = self.imp_mat.shape[1]
    imp_stats = np.zeros((len(return_periods), num_cen))
    cen_step = CONFIG.max_matrix_size.int() // self.imp_mat.shape[0]
    if not cen_step:
        raise ValueError('Increase max_matrix_size configuration parameter to > '
                         f'{self.imp_mat.shape[0]}')
    # separte in chunks
    chk = -1
    for chk in range(int(num_cen / cen_step)):
        self._loc_return_imp(np.array(return_periods),
                             self.imp_mat[:, chk * cen_step:(chk + 1) * cen_step].toarray(),
                             imp_stats[:, chk * cen_step:(chk + 1) * cen_step])
    self._loc_return_imp(np.array(return_periods),
                         self.imp_mat[:, (chk + 1) * cen_step:].toarray(),
                         imp_stats[:, (chk + 1) * cen_step:])

    return imp_stats
```

Comment: Please provide a code example, otherwise the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In the second picture you did recompute the return period curve for the default values of `(25, 50, 100, 250)`. This is different from your first picture with values of `(100, 200, 300, 500)`.